# On flutter flame 1.0.0 how to use the onComplete callback when move effect is over?

Tags: flutter, effects, flame

I was using the onComplete callback on previous flame engine version in move effect but now that version 1.0.0 was released I can’t manage to find it although it is mentioned in the documentation but not clearly and there is no example for it.

Another missing part is defining moving effect with speed instead of duration - do I need to calculate it manually? Or there is an option to provide it (I am using move.to method)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately they don't exist yet in Flame 1.0.0.

The `onFinishCallback` is merged to `main` though, so you can depend on main to get that behaviour, or wait until we release it.

To Depend on main, put this in your `pubspec.yaml` file.

```yaml
dependencies:
  flame:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flame-engine/flame.git
      ref: main
      path: packages/flame
```

`speed` for the `MoveEffect` is being worked on, but it is not done yet.
A workaround, if you are passing in a `Path` to the `MoveEffect`, is to calculate the `duration` from the speed and length of the path:

```dart
final speed = 10; // Pixels per second
List<PathMetric> metrics = path.computeMetrics().toList();
double pathLength = 0;
pm.forEach((contour){
  pathLength += contour.length;
});
final duration = pathLength / speed;
```

It's quite a cumbersome work-around so I hope that we'll release `speed` for the `MoveEffect` soon!